# Android tether, enable USB and LAN connection

Tags: android, usb, lan

I tether my 3G connection from my Android to my work PC but when I connect it, I lose connection to all my work things like database, mail, communicator, etc.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577406/enable-both-lan-intranet-and-usb-internet) but I can't figure out how to route it, my `route print` is like this:

[image: routeprint]

The IP that gives me the Android app is 10.0.0.1 (Tether application by ClockWorkMod)

Thanks for your help.